# Vlookup in Python with approximate match in a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem.

I have the base dataframe (df):

| Type | Bid | Ask | Hora | Data | Two Seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Buyer | 5711.0 | 5711.5 | 09:00:49 | 2022-01-07 | 09:00:51 |
| Seller | 5710.0 | 5710.5 | 09:00:52 | 2022-01-07 | 09:00:54 |
| Buyer | 5707.5 | 5708.0 | 09:00:53 | 2022-01-07 | 09:00:55 |
| Buyer | 5700.5 | 5701.0 | 17:59:59 | 2022-01-14 | 18:00:01 |

And I have the dataframe with prices (prices):

| Bid | Ask | Hora | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5713.0 | 5713.5 | 09:00:51 | 2022-01-07 |
| 5708.0 | 5708.5 | 09:00:55 | 2022-01-07 |
| 5703.5 | 5704.0 | 18:00:00 | 2022-01-14 |

I would like to do vlookup column Two Seconds in df prices with approximate match. The expected result would be:

| Type | Bid | Ask | Hora | Data | Two Seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Buyer | 5711.0 | 5711.5 | 09:00:49 | 2022-01-07 | 5713.5 |
| Seller | 5710.0 | 5710.5 | 09:00:52 | 2022-01-07 | 5713.0 |
| Buyer | 5707.5 | 5708.0 | 09:00:53 | 2022-01-07 | 5708.5 |
| Buyer | 5700.5 | 5701.0 | 17:59:59 | 2022-01-14 | 5704.0 |

I have tried the following, but I could not approximate match and my two dataframes are very large, so this code is very slow:

`df["Two_seconds"] = df.apply(lambda x: prices.loc[(prices["Data"] == x["Data"]) & (prices["Hora"] == x["Two_seconds"]),'Bid' if x["Tipo"] == "Buyer" else 'Ask'], axis = 1)`

How I can solve this problem?

thx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have a look at [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using vague merge.
Try to look at pd.merge_asof.

Answer (score 0):

You could try as follows:

```
# setup

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Type': {0: 'Buyer', 1: 'Seller', 2: 'Buyer', 3: 'Buyer'}, 
        'Bid': {0: 5711.0, 1: 5710.0, 2: 5707.5, 3: 5700.5}, 
        'Ask': {0: 5711.5, 1: 5710.5, 2: 5708.0, 3: 5701.0}, 
        'Hora': {0: '09:00:49', 1: '09:00:52', 2: '09:00:53', 3: '17:59:59'}, 
        'Data': {0: '2022-01-07', 1: '2022-01-07', 2: '2022-01-07', 
                 3: '2022-01-14'}, 
        'Two Seconds': {0: '09:00:51', 1: '09:00:54', 2: '09:00:55', 
                        3: '18:00:01'}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'Bid': {0: 5713.0, 1: 5708.0, 2: 5703.5}, 
         'Ask': {0: 5713.5, 1: 5708.5, 2: 5704.0}, 
         'Hora': {0: '09:00:51', 1: '09:00:55', 2: '18:00:00'}, 
         'Data': {0: '2022-01-07', 1: '2022-01-07', 2: '2022-01-14'}
         }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# code

df['Two Seconds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Two Seconds'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df2['Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Hora'], format='%H:%M:%S')

df = pd.merge_asof(df, df2, left_on='Two Seconds', 
                   right_on='Hora', suffixes=('','_y'))

df['Two Seconds'] = np.where(df['Type'] == 'Buyer', df['Ask_y'], df['Bid_y'])

df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_y')], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)

     Type     Bid     Ask      Hora        Data  Two Seconds
0   Buyer  5711.0  5711.5  09:00:49  2022-01-07       5713.5
1  Seller  5710.0  5710.5  09:00:52  2022-01-07       5713.0
2   Buyer  5707.5  5708.0  09:00:53  2022-01-07       5708.5
3   Buyer  5700.5  5701.0  17:59:59  2022-01-14       5704.0
```

Comment: @Jadson: If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question. Otherwise, please let me know where you run into issues with implementing the code.